# Postgresql instr that works with unicode

Tags: postgresql-9.2

I tried to do an instr in a postgresql query and then realized that it doesn't seem to have an instr function.

Found this url http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-porting.html#PLPGSQL-PORTING-APPENDIX

that shows how to implement instr in postgresql's plpgsql language.

However it does not seem to work with unicode varchar columns, since I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  character with byte sequence 0xe4 0xb9 0xa6 in encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in encoding "WIN1252"
```

even though I have used

```
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
```

on my client. Anyone know how to accomplish an instr with unicode?

Found out that `position` is the postgresql equivalent to `instr`, but it gives the same error as above.

This also didn't work:

```
select start from cnetd where substr(start, 6, 1) <> '/' and position('/' in convert(start, 'UTF8', 'LATIN1')) > 0 limit 90;

ERROR:  function convert(character varying, unknown, unknown) does not exist
LINE 1: ...re substr(start, 6, 1) <> '/' and position('/' in convert(st...
                                                             ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to
add explicit type casts.
```

Comment: The error message says that you are sending an invalid UTF-8 string, not that the function doesn't work with UTF-8. It has nothing to do with the functions themselves. Btw: there is also a `strpos` function in Postgres

Comment: Why would a UTF8 string be invalid?

Comment: How could I identify the offending row?

Comment: strpos also gives the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I must have quit and forgot to do:

```
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
```

when I restarted.